# How to do calculations as a column in create table SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, create-table

I want to create a table with columns that involve dividing two other columns and then multiplying a third column. The documentation on SQL Server just has an example with multiplication (example below):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Products
   (
      ProductID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
      , QtyAvailable smallint
      , UnitPrice money
      , InventoryValue AS QtyAvailable * UnitPrice
    )
```

I want to do the same thing but with the calculation I mentioned earlier, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ExampleTable
   (
      ColumnOne INT
      , ColumnTwo INT
      , ColumnThree INT
      , ColumnFour AS (ColumnOne / ColumnTwo) * ColumnThree
    )
```

I haven't had the chance to actually try it out on SQL Server but when I just tried it out on WebSQL it didn't work. Error message said:

> Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 near "QtyAvailable": syntax error).

I tried an update statement on WebSQL like

```
UPDATE ExampleTable
SET ColumnFour=(ColumnOne/ColumnTwo)*ColumnThree
```

But got 0 for ColumnFour. Tried CAST and changing to decimal data types, didn't work.

Comment: works perfectly well in SQL Server.  "I haven't had the chance to actually try it out on SQL Server " - perhaps next time you should post a question only after verifying that it is actually a problem?

Comment: WebSQL is dead - don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried creating it with the following...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Testing](
    [Qty] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Price] [DECIMAL](6, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Discount] [DECIMAL](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Calculated]  AS (([Price]/[Qty])*[Discount])
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I added 1 record as a test...

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Testing
(
    Qty,
    Price,
    Discount
)
VALUES
(   10,    
    9.99, 
    1.2  
    )
```

[image]

You might need to alter the parenthesis slightly, having the whole calculation wrapped in parenthesis, as well as the division.